# Django list_editable click not changing value

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm working with django admin and I wanted to make one of my values, `is_flagged` to be editable in the list, so I set `list_editable = ('is_flagged',)`. This produces the drop-down menu to edit that field and although I can click on the drop-down menu, when I click on a new value, nothing happens. Does anyone why this is? `is_flagged` is a `NullBooleanField`.

Comment: Do you mean once you edit it and click on `save`button changes are not reflected ?

Comment: @karthikr No. So for example, if the value set is no, and I try to click and change it to yes, when I click, the drop down menu appears, but if I try to click on yes, nothing happens. I need to use my keyboard to change the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, after I inspected the HTML, that the select form doesn't work on Firefox, but it did work on Chrome.